# Why does a first order reaction only depend on the concentration of a single reactant?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, equilibrium, kinetics

I am new to kinetics so please explain it from basic, If there is a reaction  -

$$\ce{A + B + C -> D}$$

In first order reaction rate is given by-

$\mathrm R = k[\mathrm A]$ or $\mathrm R = k[\mathrm B]$ or $\mathrm R = k[\mathrm C]$

my question is why cant $\mathrm R = k[\mathrm A]^{1/3}[\mathrm B]^{1/3}[\mathrm C]^{1/3}$
 even though order of reaction is still $1$,----- is it by definition that 1st order reaction always depend on concentration of single reactant, or is there any experimental proof for this?.

Comment: because the definition of first order reaction is that it depends on concentration of single reactant

Comment: @chemstackisunhelpful  I am sorry but your  answer is unhelpful

Comment: pl explain it briefly

Comment: $\ce{A + B + C -> D}$ is not a first order reaction.

Comment: It can have _"first order in A"_, though.

Comment: This reaction can have many intermediate steps. The rate of rate determining step is dependent on the concentration of one reactant only. So overall the reaction rate is dependent on the concentration of one reactant.

Comment: @Martin  but in my textbook all the formulas for 1st order, 2nd order and so on are derived by assuming the same reaction I have stated

Comment: @Manu but in rate determining step the reactants could have any reaction coefficient, that is  how much moles of reactants are reacting ,in the time of slowest reaction

Comment: @Martin and I think just by looking at hypothetical reaction it is impossible to tell the order of reaction

Comment: If you assert the hypothetical equation to be an elementary step, then the order is defined exactly with it. If the reaction has intermediate steps, then it is no longer an elementary reaction and you have to switch to empirically determined kinetics and everything can get a whole lot more complicated. Despite calculating every possible reaction pathway, you will no longer have any theoretical means of determining the order. And now I must admit I do no longer understand any part of your question. || If you were to add a citation for the book you're referring, that'd be awesome.

Comment: @Martin sorry but I am new to this thing, can you please state what part of question is not understood , because I have tried every possible way to explain my doubt in simple manner

Comment: Either the reaction equation is an elementary reaction, then it is not of first order; or it has an empirically determined rate law of first order, then it is not an elementary reaction. I have no clue what you are actually asking about. In the first case, the question cannot be answered. In the latter case, it is very dependent on what the reaction actually is, and the question cannot be answered in general terms. Please add a citation to the book you are using, it might help to understand your problem.

Comment: @Martin you mean to say if the reaction I have mentioned is elementary then rate would be k[A] or k[B] or k[C} but if it is complex reaction then it would become false?

Comment: No. If $\ce{A + B + C -> D}$, then the rate law would be $r = k[\ce{A}][\ce{B}][\ce{C}]$, if the rate law is determined to be $r = k[\ce{A}]$, then the reaction cannot be elementary.

Comment: I'm late but maybe I can be of some help. @martin is right, the distinction between an elementary reaction and a reaction with several elementary steps is very important. If the reaction is not elementary, the reaction orders with respect to each reagent can, at first, have any value. There are examples of first order elementary reactions, like the decomposition of ions in tandem mass spectrometry or different types of intramolecular reactions. Even if you have an elementary reaction of the type A+B-->C, it can be treated like pseudo first order in certain conditions.

Comment: @Blg90 Yeah I get it, the key to the question is if 1 of the reactant concentration in $A + B--> C$ is so greater that it almost becomes a constant,  it is excluded from rate law, even though this reaction is bimolecular, Thank you so much for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a purely mathematical definition, a first order reaction is one in which the rate is directly proportional to concentration of reactants. The thing you should look for is physical examples of this. This only happens if you have reactions where one compound is decreasing and the other one is abundance (pseudo - first order) , or , radioactive decay where the decay rate is proportional to number of atoms at a point.

The reaction you have shown with three reactants would most probably me not first order unless two of the three are abundant. So, the solution to the confusion is to think of the physically possible scenarios which the equation models instead of creating hypothetical situations and force the math to model that.

Comment: Yeah thanks for answer , after so long, I had already finished chemical kinetics !!

Comment: Did my answer help? ^^

Comment: Yeah you have written almost same, about what I thought after getting no help, But thank you for the answer it really helps a lot, to clear concepts